# Smoothly homotoping a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Start with the standard sphere $S^2$ and consider another (diffeomorphic) sphere $S$ such that there is a family of deformations of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that ends in $S$. If $S$ is positively curved, I strongly suspect that there can be a family of deformations (if not the given one) which starts with $S^2$, ends with $S$ and every member of the family in between is positively curved. How can I make this argument solid? Or is it not true at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. There are two steps to the proof:

1. (Easy and classical, going back to Gauss.) Positive curvature is equivalent to positive 2nd fundamental form, is equivalent to strict convexity of $S$ in $R^3$.
2. (Considerably harder, although, in $R^3$ this was probably known earlier): The normalized mean curvature flow of (strictly) convex hypersurfaces in $R^n$ deforms a hypersurface to the unit round sphere in $R^n$. This was first proved by G.Huisken ["Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into spheres"](http://diyhpl.us/~bryan/papers2/frey/levelsets/Huisken%20G.,%20Flow%20by%20mean%20curvature%20of%20convex%20surfaces%20nto%20spheres.pdf) in Journal of Diff. Geometry, 1984. An alternative proof is to argue intrincsically, that the set of Riemannian metrics of positive curvature on $S^2$ is connected. This can be achieved via Ricci flow (still, nonelementary). Then use Alexandrov-Pogorelov theorem that all positively curved spheres embed isometrically in $R^3$ as convex hypersurfaces and the embedding can be made continuous with respect to the metric (again, nonelementary).

Comment: I have another question about this. What if one asks the same question, but now starting and ending in surfaces of negative curvature? From what I have seen of the Ricci flow, it somehow tends to favor positive curvatures, that is, tends to preserve positive curvatures. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: @Guest: In the negative curvature setting it only makes sense to ask if the space of metrics of negative curvature on a (closed) surface is connected, since they will not embed isometrically to $R^3$. The answer is again positive and follows from Hamilton's work (you need to use the normalized flow: It will converge to a constant negative curvature metric and negativity of the curvature is preserved by the flow). See http://faculty.math.tsinghua.edu.cn/~lma/lectures/ricciface2.pdf for the exposition of Hamilton's proof.